# Usage of trunkline/trunk line to refer to a highway

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Is anyone familiar with usage of the word *trunkline*/*trunk line* to refer generally to a highway, outside of the specific case of "Any road under the jurisdiction of the Michigan Department of Transportation" that I found on Wiktionary? I've read elsewhere that it is used in Britain and some Northern European countries to refer to highways.

Separately, I'd appreciate some insight on the etymology of the term.

Comment: Basicallly, the *trunk* is the main part of a (literal or figurative) "body", as distinguished from its appendages.  [OED definition 4a.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/206968?redirectedFrom=trunk+route#eid17384465) *Anatomy. The main body or line of a blood vessel, nerve, or similar structure, as distinct from its branches; also transferred the main line of a river, railway, telegraph or telephone, road or canal system; see trunk-drainage n., trunk-glacier n. at Compounds 1b, trunk line n.* Does that help?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trunk%20line

Answer (score 1):

In Britain most roads are the responsibilty of the local authority for the area in which they are located but major routes are the responsibility of the Ministry of Transport (MoT).  Some of these are Motorways which are a special category of road but non-motorway MoT-maintained roads are known as Trunk roads.

These are not trunk line or trunkline roads, they are trunk roads and the term goes back, I think, to the 1930s (the first Motorway was opened in the late 1950s). In Britain 'trunk line' is a term which used to be applied to long distance telephone lines but is now obsolete.

Comment: Now the Department for Transport.